# How do I find a value in an array in the specific situation?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am creating an array that stores a name and a bowling score from the same line and then using Split() to split the name and score into two separate arrays.  Then I need to find the highest score along with the name with the highest score and write it to the console using a method somehow.

Here is what i have so far.  Thanks.

```
    const int SIZE = 10;

    string[] arrayNames = new string[SIZE];
    int[] arrayScores = new int[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        Write("Enter the name and score of a player on one line seperated by a space or press Enter to stop ");

        string input = ReadLine();

        if (input == ""){
            break;
        }
        string[] scoreInfo = input.Split();
        arrayNames[i] = scoreInfo[0];

        bool valid = false;
        do{
            if (input == ""){
                break;
            }
            valid = int.TryParse(scoreInfo[1], out arrayScores[i]);
            valid = valid && (arrayScores[i] <= 300);

        } while (!valid);

    }

    int max = bowling.CalcHighest(arrayScores);
    int min = bowling.CalcLowest(arrayScores);
    int average = bowling.CalcAverage(arrayScores);
```

Comment: Take a debugger and step through your program. On every step check that every variable contains the value you expect it to contain. When you see a mismatch - then you found a bug.

Comment: Hold on, you shouldn't edit your question after accepting an answer. This will be very confusing to people. I strongly encourage you to change it back to the original and post the follow up as a second question.

Comment: I don't think I can change it back.

Comment: If you have a follow up question, please ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop, you already have the highest score, you just need to keep track of it. `arrayScores[i]`

Here's what I'd do:

```
const int SIZE = 10;

string[] arrayNames = new string[SIZE];
int[] arrayScores = new int[SIZE];

int highScore = 0;
string winner = "";

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    Write("Enter the name and score of a player on one line seperated by a space or press Enter to stop ");

    string input = ReadLine();

    if (input == ""){
        break;
    }
    string[] scoreInfo = input.Split();
    arrayNames[i] = scoreInfo[0];

    bool valid = false;
    do{
        if (input == ""){
            break;
        }
        valid = int.TryParse(scoreInfo[1], out arrayScores[i]);
        valid = valid && (arrayScores[i] <= 300);

        if(valid && arrayScores[i] > highScore){
            highScore = arrayScores[i];
            winner = arrayNames[i];
        }

    } while (!valid);

}
```

Then just grab the winner and highScore after the completion of the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you aren't maintaining a reference between the name and the score.

When you read in a line you are separating the values into `arrayNames[i]` and `arrayScores[i]`.

Consider using a Dictionary maybe instead of two separate arrays.

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dict.Add(name, score);
```

Then do your calculations using the dictionary as a parameter rather than the array. If you're using System.Linq you can do all the calculations on the dictionary real easy:

```
var orderedDict = dict.OrderByDescending(d => d.Value); //This orders the dictionary by the scor
var first = orderedDict.First(); //This gets the highest score
var last = orderedDict.Last(); //This gets the lowest score
var average = dict.Sum(s => s.Value)/dict.Count(); //This is the average

var firstName = first.Key; //Name of winner
var lastName = last.Key; //Name of loser
```